# Buffer Overflow to Modify the Return Address

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, buffer-overflow

I'm needing to modify the return address so I can call print_good function. I need an offset value, and a hex value to store to do so. The offset that I calculated from using obj is 0xcd, which was gotten 0x40074e(the puts function which I believe prints out try again) minus 400686(The address of the print_good function that I want to call). The hex value that I believe is correct is 400686, which is the address of the print_good value. Putting the offset value I got and the hex value I got doesn't give the correct answer.

I'm pretty sure the hex value is 0x400686, but correct me if I'm wrong. The offset value I believe could be off.

I'm given the code and the executable. I need to find the password which is an offset value and a hex value. I got the addresses using objdump and looking at its code.

If you want to try it yourself to help me, here's the file to download the executable:
The executable:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/disui6pwcb55ing/Ch3_07_CanaryBypass

The c code:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/yu3j3dxg476qy8c/Ch3_07_CanaryBypass.c

The c Code written here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define USERDEF 30

char msg[] =
"Stack canaries and non-executable stacks make stack exploitation difficult. Such\n"
"techniques, however, do not protect against return-oriented programming where\n"
"only the return addresses on the stack are targeted.  In this level, you control\n"
"a single write into a vulnerable buffer in the function prompt_user.  Overflow\n"
"the buffer to modify the return address beyond the stack canary so that it\n"
"points to a function of your choice.  The level will prompt you with an offset\n"
"(in decimal) from the beginning of the buffer that will be written into followed\n"
"by a hexadecimal value that will be written there (e.g. scanf(\"%d %x\");).\n"
"The program will then write the hexadecimal value to a location computed\n"
"using the offset.  To determine how close you are, examine the pointer\n"
"being used to write into the stack and how far away it is from the value\n"
"of $rsp when the retq instruction at the end of prompt_user is reached.\n\n";

void print_good() {
    printf("Good Job.\n");
    exit(0);
}

void print_msg() {
    printf("%s",msg);
}

void prompt_user() {
    char buffer[30];
    int offset;
    char *user_addr;
    char **over_addr;
    printf("Enter the password: ");
    scanf("%d %lx", &offset, (unsigned long *) &user_addr);
    over_addr = (char **) (buffer + offset);
    *over_addr = user_addr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    print_msg();
    prompt_user();
    printf("Try again.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You calculated the offset wrong. It's not the difference between the two functions, it's the difference between the `buffer` and the return address location on the stack.

Comment: could you edit the program eg. with a hex-editor? then you could pick a good spot and place a call to the function. anyway: for the intended way:what is the string you tried?

Comment: How do I determine the register of the buffer?

Comment: I found the answer. rsp register difference between the rbp register was the offset. The hex value I had was correct.